# Template userid in AWS policy

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Is there a way to template the userid in bucket policies, so that it references the owner of the bucket?

So that instead of `arn:aws:iam::1234567:user/some_iam_user` I could use `arn:aws:iam::{genericstring}:user/some_iam_user`?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would make sense... `user/michael` in *my* account is not in any sense equivalent to `user/michael` in *your* account.  Without a specific account id, a given username has no semantic meaning. What problem would this solve for you?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot The numeric string identifies the aws account though, so `arn:aws:iam::12345:user/foo` and `arn:aws:iam::12345:user/bar` are both my accounts. I just want to skip writing `12345` if I'm already writing the policy for a bucket owned by `12345`.

Comment: If you create these rules as IAM user or group policy instead of bucket policy, you don't have to specify the user at all... the user is implicit because, hey, that's who the policy is attached to.  That's much more scalable and manageable since they all go in one place. With this, I rarely use *bucket* policies for user-related S3 permissions, fwiw.